# Securing API Keys on clients (JavaScript, Android, iOS, etc.)

Tags: javascript, api, security

I am working on an API-centric web application with a custom authorization method that consists of building a string based off of the request method, URL, params, public API key and encoded by a private API key.  This works fine on the server side, but on client side the private API key (and authorization method) will be vulnerable.  I've spent the last hour or so looking on a good way to secure this API key and the best method I could find is by proxying through my server, but I am still not sure 100% on this.

First of all, should I be worried?  I want to make security a priority in my web application, but anything that will deal with modifying a user's account will need a temporary, encrypted token to authorize the request (in addition to the HMAC hash).

My understanding from proxying was that you would make a request to your server, which would then encrypt with the private key and return the information..but how would the server validate that the request came from a source with a valid API key?

Can anyone provide any insight as to what I should do?  I feel like this could potentially be a vulnerability for any client-side code including JavaScript, iOS, and Android.

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Comment: in what way would the private key be vulnerable? you have to give the key to the client or it won't work...

Comment: Currently the clients would only be my official apps (web and mobile). But the private key and authorization method would be visible in the JavaScript source for any AJAX calls to be possible on the site.

Comment: Why do you want to make a custom authorization method? You're usually better off using a standard method that's been thought through, stood the test of time, etc.

What is the threat model that you're most concerned about? 3rd-party apps using your API?

Comment: I'm most concerned about 3rd parties (not necessarily apps) making unauthorized calls.  So someone using the API to write a script to register numerous accounts, or scrape all of our data (we have a lot of valuable data that is obtained through a search API), etc.  I feel like the closet fit would be oauth, but isn't that tailored more towards granting 3rd party applications access to a users account?

Comment: And @Yusuf X, even if I used a standard like oAuth or basic HTTP...how would I hide the secret key and/or passwords in a JavaScript file?

Comment: You're right, oAuth is to authorize 3rd parties without giving them your password. For what you're trying to accomplish (if I understand your problem), the only way is for the user to authorize with a password. You can't hide an API key in the website.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I'll just do handful of obfuscation methods to make it more difficult to utilize (and I can always break an API key if it is being misused).  The good news is there is no security risk because there is a whole secret (server side) tokening system for user accounts, and the only thing that is at risk with an API key is  just stealing our search results in JSON format (rather than HTML scraping)..

Comment: Shouldnt this question be in http://security.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can never trust the client. Even if you obfuscate, someone could still figure it out. For example, an adversary could reverse-engineer the obfuscation algorithm, look at the device memory, or even capture what's sent over the wire.

However, you can still make a secure app by enforcing security on the server side. For example, users should need to be authenticated in order to successfully make privileged API requests.

Also, you can enforce API usage on the server side, whether by input validation, rate limiting, or IP address tracking.

Comment: Every time I come back to this because someone upvoted the question, I see "you can never trust the client." I have become a big fan of this mentality and it has even helped streamline some API creation (i.e. there's no need to take a password confirmation in registration, since the client could just fake this anyways).

Comment: @sam The confirmation is for the user to ensure they typed what they think they typed.  It's less likely to mistype a password twice the wrong way.