# Keep API Keys in ios app

Tags: ios, api-key

What is the best place to put API keys in your ios App. These keys are secret. So is there some best practice to put such keys in your iOS app, or just put them in a normal file is okay?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Securing API Keys on clients (JavaScript, Android, iOS, etc.)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17056822/securing-api-keys-on-clients-javascript-android-ios-etc)

Comment: @Almo Does not answer the question other than saying not to. Does not mention using the Keychain.

Comment: Here's another that does mention the keychain: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21766343/ios-is-there-a-safe-way-to-include-an-api-key-in-the-code

Comment: How is the keychain a solution? The keys would already need to be part of the app, in some form, for the app to be able to write them to the keychain.

Comment: @Madu when are the keys saved, at compile-time or later at run-time?

Answer (score 1):

Put secrets in the Keychain.

Putting them in a file is insecure, there many utilities that can acccess a file if one has access to the iDevice and it is unlocked.

Comment: How do the keys get to the keychain? The OP seems to be talking about keys that must be bundled with the app. You can't bundle keychain entries with the app without the keys already being part of the app.

Comment: True if that is what the OP is asking. If the keys are available at compile time they could be put in the app but the OP mentions putting them in a file. I have added a comment asking this.